# how to concatenate two columns from mysql in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get all the names from MySQL into a dropdown list using PHP.
I connected to MySQL using PDO. currently I can get only the first name, But I want the names to be first name + last name in the drop down list but I couldn't concatenate them.

I tried to concatenate them like this:

```
<select class="un">
        <option class="op" value="" disabled selected style="color:gray">Username</option>
        <?php foreach ($result as $output) { ?>
    <option class="op"> <?php echo $output["firstname"+"lastname"]; ?></option>
<?php } ?>  
            </select>
```

but that didn't work out for me.

```
$query="select * from user_details"; 
$exec = $conn->prepare($query);
$exec->execute();
$rc = $exec->rowCount();
$result=$exec->fetchAll(); 

<select class="un">
        <option class="op" value="" disabled selected style="color:gray">Username</option>
        <?php foreach ($result as $output) { ?>
    <option class="op"> <?php echo $output["firstname"]; ?></option>
<?php } ?>  
            </select>
```

it worked only with one column which is the firstname but I want it to be both firstname + lastname

Comment: It's `$output["firstname"] . " "  . $output["lastname"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update this view code:

```
<select class="un">
        <option class="op" value="" disabled selected style="color:gray">Username</option>
        <?php foreach ($result as $output) { ?>
    <option class="op"> <?php echo $output["firstname"] .' '.$output["lastname"]; ?></option>
<?php } ?>  
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Mysql you can try this `concat()`

```
$query="select concat(firstname,' ',lastname) as fullname from user_details"; 
$exec = $conn->prepare($query);
$exec->execute();
$rc = $exec->rowCount();
$result=$exec->fetchAll(); 

<select class="un">
        <option class="op" value="" disabled selected style="color:gray">Username</option>
        <?php foreach ($result as $output) { ?>
    <option class="op"> <?php echo $output["fullname"]; ?></option>
<?php } ?>  
</select>
```